# Accessing property of casted object returning unexpected results on Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I have a snippet of code that casts a TFmxObject to a TForm and accesses it's Height and Width properties that works fine. AControl is a standard TControl, and the Parent property is a TfmxObject. edited: I am first checking with the IS keyword that the parent is in fact a TForm.

```
LPar:=TControl.Create(AControl);
LPar.Height:=(AControl.Parent As TForm).Height;
LPar.Width:=(AControl.Parent As TForm).Width;
```

On Windows, this code returns the values of Height and Width that I would expect and assigns it to LPar.Height and LPar.Width (Also a standard TControl), but as soon as I change the target platform to Android and debug using usb debugging on the device, the assignment is not an actual value but something like 6.2645644...+036 (Both Height and Width have the same invalid value).

I don't know if the problem lies with casting the TFmxObject as a TForm or.. really where to start with troubleshooting further. I've tried assigning AControl.Parent to a local TFmxObject and then performing the cast on the local variable (same results) and I have also tried casting using this syntax as well

```
TForm(AControl.Parent)
```

with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How certain are you the parent really is a TForm? If you test with "is", what happens?

Comment: Sorry, I left that out, I am first checking whether or not the parent "IS" a Tform, otherwise, if it is not, I perform other logic which is working correctly

Comment: @DavidM: If the `Parent` were not really a `TForm`, the `as` operator would raise an exception (unless that is broken on Android).

Comment: Yes, though the hard-cast won't, but I'd still like to check. Clearly something accessing the form's properties isn't working; step 1 is, is it a form? Is it a FMX form or a VCL form? (What if the wrong unit is in the uses clause?) Etc etc. Finding out the class and the cast behaviour seems a good first step.

Comment: 1. yes, its a form (a descendant from TForm, it is actually a custom form, but accessing the property in windows works just fine)
2. it is FMX, and will have to be since I'm using android
3. the wrong unit shouldn't be an issue since I do not have any conditionally defined units (no swapping based on platform)

Hopefully that clears a few things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by installing Berlin 10.1 and just setting up the environment from scratch (installing packages, updating library paths etc...)
I don't know if this was fixed by using the newer version of Delphi, or if it was me re-installing my packages.